# Windows 7 Japanese OS

Tags: windows-7, operating-system, windows-7-x64

I am using Windows 7 64 bit English version but I need Japanese version too in another system.

Is there anything called Japanese OS?

What is the difference between having a Japanese OS or installing Japanese Language pack over English OS so as to display messages in English.

Is there any performance difference between English and Japanese OS?

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to change its Region and Language settings to Japanese including its format and display language. But first you'll have to download Japanese IME.